# how to draw the second curve based Y2axis while the first curve is based on YAxis?

Tags: zedgraph

I'm using ZedGraph.

I have 2 curves to draw, the first curve is based on the scale of YAxis, while the second one is based on the Y2Axis, the value in first curve is far bigger than the second value. 
In my project, both curves are based on YAxis, which makes the graph ugly.

Does anyone has experience to draw second curve based on the Y2Axis?

Here is my code: (What should I change?)

```
PointPairList p1 = new PointPairList(),
p2 = new PointPairList();
//code to add data into p1 and p2

GraphPane gp = new GraphPane();
gp.AddCurve(p1, "", Color.Black);
gp.AddCurve(p2, "", Color.Blue);

gp.XAxis.Scale.Min = v1;
gp.Y2Axis.Scale.Max = v2;
gp.AxisChange(); 
gp.XAxis.Scale.IsUseTenPower = false; 
gp.Y2Axis.Scale.IsUseTenPower=false;
```

Thank you.

---

If I want to set the `Y2Axis` share the same grid of `Y1Axis`, after:

```
LineItem curveY2 = gp.AddCurve(p2, "", Color.Blue);
```

...

```
curveY2 .IsY2Axis = true;
```

i.e., the grid is based on `Y1Axis`, then `Y2Axis` has the same grid but with different lable.
For example, `Y1Axis` is from 1 to 300, and have 7 rows, however `Y2Axis` has 1 to 20, I want the `Y2Axis` also have 7 rows (same as the `Y1Axis`), which function should I use?

Answer (score 4):

```
LineItem curveY2 = gp.AddCurve(p2, "", Color.Blue);
...
curveY2 .IsY2Axis = true;
//If you have more than one axis on the related side, you have to assign the index of the axis
curveY2 .YAxisIndex = 0;
```